# Unable to send notification using node js and firestore/firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created small function to send notification to the user. The token id will be fetched from database and the notification should be send to that device. Even though the function is running absolutely Okay in console. Even I get the response that I have set if notification is send.But that does not reach to device.
I am trying to send notification to Iphone device mainly Ipad

Here is the Code

```
exports.SendNotification = functions.firestore.document("UserData/{user_id}").onWrite((change, context) => {

    const user_id = context.params.user_id;



    console.log('We have a notification to send to :', user_id);




    return admin.firestore().collection("UserData").doc(user_id).get()

       .then(snapshot2 =>
         {

           const Message =snapshot2.data().msg;
           const token_id =snapshot2.data().token_id;

          console.log(" Message: ", Message);
          console.log(" Token_id: ",token_id);



        const payload =
        {
            notification:
            {
                title: "Notification",
                body: "Hi this is to notify you",
                icon: "default"
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)
                    .then(response =>
                    {
                      return  console.log('Second notification is also send successfully');
                    });
    });
});
```

Comment: `notification` can only have `title` and `body` in it.  To catch your error, add `.catch(console.log)` after the close of your `.then` block on sendToDevice.

Comment: this will give error throw or return something like this

Comment: Can you send a test message to the device using the Firebase Console?

Comment: i haven't try till now